# When working with Python 3 and Django do you modify pip packages when debugging?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pip

I am coming from PHP and playing with Python at the moment. In PHP, composer would install dependencies into ./vendor within your project dir and you can modify them in any way when working. This is usually useful when debugging or when you want to try something out or even to look up some function signature quickly. In Python I used pip to install dependencies off a provided requirements.txt file but the packages get installed into a system dir and it doesn't look like they are meant to be modified.

What is your workflow for Python apps: do you modify pip packages and if yes, how do you do that?

Comment: I think this question will likely be closed. You should look into Anaconda or mkvirtualenv. Those will let you keep your `pip` installed packages in a project-specific location.

Answer (score 2):

In my projects I use [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv), and I love it.

You can setup an isolated environment for your projects python dependencies with:

```
pip install pyenv pipenv # Pipenv uses pyenv to download required versions of python.
pipenv install --three Django  # pipenv install --python "3.6.2" Django 
pipenv shell  # This opens up shell in the virtualenv
```

I usually set an environment variable `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1` before I create/use the virtualenv because I prefer to have my virtualenv in my project folder, you can check out the help/docs for more info.

If you cd to the virtualenv folder created by pipenv you'll see all your installed packages.  As long as you `source` this virtualenv environment (with `source .venv/bin/activate`) or run `pipenv shell` before running your python commands they will not use system dependencies, but rather the python version and dependencies specified in the virtualenv.

Comment: Hadn't heard of pipenv, but thank you.  Testing this morning and am extremely intrigued.  May become a convert.  Thx!

Comment: What is the lock file in a pipenv project.  That is something I am not familiar with in Python/pip/virtualenv?

Comment: The Pipfile.lock is, im pretty sure, a list of all your packages, their versions and hashes, and their dependency trees.  This is so that when you run `pipenv install` on another machine with the pipfile.lock present it doesn't have to perform dependency resolution.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at using something like [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  Setup a project specific python instance and use the requirements.txt file for that instance.  You can modify the code for each dependency by you might want to look at using pydb for debugging instead.

Comment: Before `virtualenvwrapper` shouldn't the OP look into `virtualenv`? :-)